# Call to XCreateColormap Creates Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, opengl, x11, glx

For some reason, my Call to `XCreateColormap` in XLib is giving me a segmentation fault. The funny thing is that most of the code that I've used is almost identical to the code that I've seen on the net which shows how to create a window and OpenGL context using XLib and GLX.

In terms of details, I have a struct called `OVI_UnixDisplayData`, which basically acts as a container for all of the relevant X Window/GLX data used to create a window and assign it a context. I initially have a function which is designed to create a context and then return a pointer to that data struct. That struct is referred to as just `dat` (for data).

**Occurance of SegFault**

```
dat->fbConfigs = glXChooseFBConfig( dat->display, DefaultScreen( dat->display ), visualAttr, &dat->framebuffCount );

if ( !dat->fbConfigs || dat->framebuffCount < 1 )
{
    puts( OVI_ERR_GLX_FRAME_BUF_CFG );
    exit( 1 );
}

printf( OVI_STAT_GLX_FRAME_BUFF_CFG_COUNT, dat->framebuffCount );

dat->visualinfo = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( dat->display, dat->fbConfigs[ dat->fbCountId ] );

printf( OVI_STAT_GLX_FRAME_BUFF_VIS_ID, dat->visualinfo->visualid );

puts( OVI_STAT_X_COLORMAP_CREATE );

dat->setwinatt->colormap = XCreateColormap(
            dat->display,
            RootWindow( dat->display, dat->visualinfo->screen ),
            dat->visualinfo->visual, AllocNone );
```

I've checked my own versions of GLX, which *are* being returned as 1.4, so that can't be the problem. Ontop of that, in my debugger, I know that `dat->visualinfo->visual->ext_data` holds the value of 0x0, so I wouldn't be surprised if that has something to do with it. The problem is that I don't know how (if at all), and I wouldn't know what function to call to get it *properly* initialized, as its behavior seems to be that of more of a C-like implementation of a linked-list.

**Can someone shed some light on this?** I need info, and while a Google search has given me some results on other people experiencing seg-faults from this function call, none of them have had a reason even similar to mine for this happening.

If it means anything, I'm running GLX 1.4, and OpenGL 4.2

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger? You will then see exactly where it crashes and will be able to examine variables. Do a Google search for `gdb tutorials` to learn how to use the most common debugger in UNIX/Linux systems.

Comment: Please provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, if you read the entire thing you would know that I already have run my debugger on this.

Comment: can you provide trace of X requests from xtrace (http://xtrace.alioth.debian.org/ ) or xscope ( http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xscope/ )

Comment: @n.m.
Well, mine agrees that it is. Your comment does not help the issue, for one, because I've already compiled this. What your asking for is essentially for me to post the entire header file, along with the source file, which doesn't make sense, as that is out of scope of the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

The segmentation fault has occured to the fact that I had `XSetWindowAttributes` allocated as a pointer to an address. The issue was resolved when I chose to allocate it on the stack, instead.

Consider this issue resolved.

Comment: Aaaah! Thank you for posting the solution... This is so odd, but worked for me.